Stopping the shape from moving directly past a wall when checking for a collision
So I am attempting to program a physics simulation in Pygame and am having trouble adding solidity to the walls. As of now, I have only programmed solidity for the left wall, and the squares do initially stop moving at collision for a split second. However, as I continue to drag a square for a while after it collides with the wall, the square shifts to the other side, moving past the wall (AKA tunneling). I logged the coordinates of the square when it first collides with the left wall, which is at 138 in the X direction. I realised that the square's x coordinate kept decreasing as I continued to drag the square into the wall after the collision. At some point, the coordinate goes below 94 (the left side of the left wall), and that is when it teleports to the other side. This is because I wrote a condition where the square's left side is set to the wall's right side (138 in the X direction) whenever its left side is greater than 94 (the wall's right side) and less than 138. And whenever the square's left side goes below 94, this condition does not hold true anymore, thus shifting it through the wall. How do I make sure that the square's X coordinate does not continue to decrease after it has hit this wall? The same thing occurs on the other side of the wall as well when it collides with the shape.
Here is a portion of my code with the parts that are relevant to this bug.
import pygame
import sys
import math

pygame.init()
screen_width = 800
screen_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)

shapes = [
{"type": "rect", "color": red, "rect": pygame.Rect(153, 486, 40, 40), "velocity": 0},
{"type": "rect", "color": green, "rect": pygame.Rect(223, 486, 40, 40), "velocity": 0},
{"type": "rect", "color": blue, "rect": pygame.Rect(340, 486, 40, 40), "velocity": 0},
{"type": "circle", "color": green, "center": [420, 505], "radius": 20, "velocity": 0},
{"type": "circle", "color": red, "center": [490, 505], "radius": 20, "velocity": 0},
{"type": "circle", "color": yellow, "center": [550, 505], "radius": 20, "velocity": 0}
]


#Defining the boundaries as rectangles
left_boundary = pygame.Rect(133, 162, 5, 366)
right_boundary = pygame.Rect(667, 162, 5, 366)
bottom_boundary = pygame.Rect(133, 528, 539, 5)

#This is where the function for collision detection is
#If the left side of the square touches the boundary, the square is suppose to stop moving and shouldn't continue past the wall
def check_boundaries(shape, boundary):
    if shape["type"] == "rect":
        rect = shape["rect"]

        if rect.colliderect(boundary):
            if rect.left <= boundary.right and rect.left >= boundary.left:
                rect.left = boundary.right
            
            if rect.right >= boundary.left and rect.right <= boundary.right:
                rect.right = boundary.left

running = True
dragging = False
dragged_shape = None

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        #If we click on a shape with the mouse, that shape's dragging property becomes true
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_pos = event.pos
            for shape in shapes:
                if shape["type"] == "rect" and shape["rect"].collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    dragging = True
                    dragged_shape = shape
                    d_x = shape["rect"].x - mouse_pos[0]
                    d_y = shape["rect"].y - mouse_pos[1]
                
        
        #Upon releasing the mouse, the shape's dragging property becomes false
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            dragging = False
            dragged_shape = None

        #This code allows us to drag the shape by updating its posision to the displacement of the mouse
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if dragging and dragged_shape:
                mouse_pos = event.pos
                if dragged_shape["type"] == "rect":
                    dragged_shape["rect"].x,  dragged_shape["rect"].y = mouse_pos[0]+d_x, mouse_pos[1]+d_y
       
                #Calling the check_boundaries function                                      
                check_boundaries(dragged_shape, left_boundary)

        #Drawing the shapes and walls on the screen
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        #Drawing the shapes and walls of the container 
        for shape in shapes:
            if shape["type"] == "rect":
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, shape["color"], shape["rect"])
            elif shape["type"] == "circle":
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, shape["color"], shape["center"], shape["radius"])

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, left_boundary)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, right_boundary)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, bottom_boundary)

        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)

I have tried to increase the fps and also attempted to calculate the speed of the dragging shape to decrement a certain amount of pixels while the square is running into a wall, but none of those seem to work.
